# vi setting for new window

Tags: terminal, configuration, gnome-terminator

I'm using Terminator for my terminal emulator. Whenever I open it, the initial workspace comes with the setting I defined in the config file. But whenever I split the workspace, the new workspace comes with the default setting. Here is part of my config file:

```
[global_config]
  enabled_plugins = LaunchpadCodeURLHandler, APTURLHandler, LaunchpadBugURLHandler
  focus = mouse
  title_transmit_fg_color = "#000000"
  sticky = True
[keybindings]
  new_tab = <Ctrl>n
  next_tab = <Ctrl>Right
  split_vert = <Ctrl>v
  split_horiz = <Ctrl>h
  prev_tab = <Ctrl>Left
[profiles]
  [[default]]
  [[solarized-light]]
    palette = "#073642:#d30102:#859900:#b58900:#6c71c4:#d33682:#2aa198:#839496:#586e75:#cb4b16:#859900:#b58900:#268bd2:#dc322f:#2aa198:#93a1a1"
    use_system_font = False
    cursor_color = "#002b36"
    foreground_color = "#002b36"
    show_titlebar = False
    background_color = "#eee8d5"
  [[solarized-dark]]
    palette = "#073642:#d30102:#859900:#b58900:#6c71c4:#d33682:#2aa198:#839496:#586e75:#cb4b16:#859900:#b58900:#268bd2:#dc322f:#2aa198:#93a1a1"
    use_system_font = False
    cursor_color = "#eee8d5"
    foreground_color = "#eee8d5"
    show_titlebar = False
    background_color = "#002b36"
  [[Noor]]
[layouts]
  [[default]]
    [[[child]]]
      type = Terminal
      parent = window0
      profile = solarized-dark
    [[[window0]]]
      type = Window
      parent = ""
      profile = solarized-light
[plugins]
~
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that new splits or tabs will always use the default profile, and ignore the layouts. Layouts seem to only apply to new windows.

Unfortunately, the documentation and man pages don't provide any more detail for me to refer you to.